# Eloquent: with() fields return null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function messageUsers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("MessageUser", "user1_id")->orWhere("user2_id", $this->id);
    }
}

class MessageUser extends Model
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("Message");
    }
}

class Message extends Model
{
    public function sender()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("User", "user_id", "id");
    }
}
```

I'd like to get specific fields from sender() in Message class. However,

```
$user = User::find(2);
$msg_user = $user->messageUsers()->find(15);
$tmp = $msg_user->messages()->with(["sender" => function($query) { $query->select("username"); }])
```

$tmp returns null, while:

```
$msg_user->messages()->with("sender")
```

returns all fields as expected.

Why with() function doesn't return value of passed field name(s)?

Thanks.

**UPDATE** Here the tables structure:

```
user:
- id
- username

message_users
- id
- user1_id
- user2_id

messages
- id
- message_user_id
- user_id
- content
```

Comment: Hello, can you please post your DB schema? Or at least the tables you are trying to relate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One stipulation for modifying the `select` clause on the relationship is that the foreign key field must be included, otherwise Laravel won't know how to link the related objects to each other once they're retrieved from the database.

Add in the foreign key to your select clause:

```
$tmp = $msg_user->messages()->with(["sender" => function($query) {
    $query->select("id", "username");
}]);
```